# in swift converting JSON data to string doesn't print correctly

Tags: json, swift, logging

I am converting the (NS)Data to a string in Swift (2.2 atm) coming from a service call and I want to display it in the console. so

```
let s = String(data: data!, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)
print(s)
```

what I see has escaped character which is fairly useless to read

```
Optional("{\"assets\":{\"err-fc2264112130e2c90bef0887b4367bb7\":{\"errors\": ...
```

is there a clever way to have it show the JSON without the \" and missing the carriage returns. I thought of running the NSJSONSerialization twice (from data to foundation back to data with formatting on and then to string). I can do that but I wonder if there is some less irritating way.

Answer (score 0):

You convert data to string, so the result you have is corrent, it's optional string.

If you want to get json result, you should just serialize the data.

simply,

```
if let json = NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data!, 
    options: NSJSONReadingOptions.MutableContainers, error: nil) {
    print(json)
}
```

Comment: That doesn't print the JSON, it prints the foundation objects which is not the same. I want to see what the server sent as is.

Answer (score 0):

Try below solution:

```
let myStr = String(data: data!, encoding: .utf8)!
print(myStr as AnyObject)
```

There are more options, you can find in this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/68760531/3840884